# How do i get values from the dropdown menu?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, drop-down-menu

I have made a simpel dropdown menu where i can select `navn` but I dont know how to get the `sukker_g` values from later parts of the array. What I want is to get the `sukker_g` value so I can use thise numbers later in the prodject

```
 var person = [
    {navn:"Imsdal Aktiv", volum:0.5, sukker_g:27.3},
    {navn:"Coca-Cola", volum:0.5, sukker_g:53},
    {navn:"Iste", volum:0.5, sukker_g:44},
    {navn:"Red Bull", volum:0.250, sukker_g:27.5},
    {navn:"Iskaffe", volum:0.330, sukker_g:16.5},
    {navn:"Frappuchino", volum:0.250, sukker_g:25.5},
    {navn:"Solrik", volum:0.250, sukker_g:29.7},
    {navn:"Litago", volum:0.5, sukker_g:20},
    {navn:"Vitamin Boost", volum:0.5, sukker_g:20},
    {navn:"Solbærsirup", volum:0.250, sukker_g:24.5},
    {navn:"Sjokolademelk", volum:0.250, sukker_g:12.5},
]
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");

for(var i = 0; i < person.length; i++) {
    var opt = person[i].navn;
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;

    select.appendChild(el);         
}
```

what i have so far works fine but can somone help me with the last part of geting the values of `sukker_g` to the selected `navn`

Comment: Where you want sukker_g to be implemented, I mean where ?

Comment: the ting is that i want to be able to do something like this `button.onclick = function() { svar.innerHTML = "= " + form.temperatur.value * person[0].sukker_g + " g sukker daglig. " ; return false; };` with `sukker_g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
el.value = opt;
```

… to this:

```
el.value = i;
```

You can then access the selected `sukker_g` like this:

```
person[select.value].sukker_g
```

---

Below is an object-oriented approach, in which the constructor is called `People`, and `navn()`, `volum()`, and `sukker_g` methods are created.

It creates a `person` object:

```
var person= new People();
```

… and you can refer to its properties like this:

```
person.navn()
person.volum()
person.sukker_g()
```

**Snippet**

```js
function People() {
  var person = [
      {navn:"Imsdal Aktiv", volum:0.5, sukker_g:27.3},
      {navn:"Coca-Cola", volum:0.5, sukker_g:53},
      {navn:"Iste", volum:0.5, sukker_g:44},
      {navn:"Red Bull", volum:0.250, sukker_g:27.5},
      {navn:"Iskaffe", volum:0.330, sukker_g:16.5},
      {navn:"Frappuchino", volum:0.250, sukker_g:25.5},
      {navn:"Solrik", volum:0.250, sukker_g:29.7},
      {navn:"Litago", volum:0.5, sukker_g:20},
      {navn:"Vitamin Boost", volum:0.5, sukker_g:20},
      {navn:"Solbærsirup", volum:0.250, sukker_g:24.5},
      {navn:"Sjokolademelk", volum:0.250, sukker_g:12.5},
  ]
  var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");

  for(var i = 0; i < person.length; i++) {
    var opt = person[i].navn;
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = i;
    select.appendChild(el);         
  }

  this.navn= function() {return person[select.value].navn};
  this.volum= function() {return person[select.value].volum};
  this.sukker_g= function() {return person[select.value].sukker_g};
} //People

var person= new People();

function showPerson() {
  alert(person.navn()+'\r'+person.volum()+'\r'+person.sukker_g());
}
```

```html
<select id="selectNumber"></select>
<button onclick="showPerson()">Show person</button>
```

Comment: why is it that if i try to `console.log` what you have used an `alert`on it only shows for a split second and the disapear?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate that in Chrome.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why your version of Chrome would do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make use of `data-*` attribute available in the html5 these days:

```
for (var i = 0; i < person.length; i++) {
  var opt = person[i].navn;
  var skValue = person[i].sukker_g; // get it here
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  el.setAttribute('data-value', skValue); // set it here
  select.appendChild(el);
}
```

it will result in this:

```
<option value='Imsdal Aktiv' data-value='27.3'>Imsdal Aktiv</option>
```

and later you can use this to get that data-value with this:

```
var getSkkg = document.getElementById("selectNumber").options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.value
```

```js
document.getElementById("selectNumber").onchange = function(e) {
//window.onload = function() {
  var getvalue = document.getElementById("selectNumber").options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.value;
  alert(getvalue);
};
```

```html
<select id='selectNumber'>
  <option data-value='chooose'>chooose.....</option>
  <option data-value='custom-dataset'>custom-dataset</option>
  <option>afasfasdfasd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: but how do i get the value of the selected object to implement in an later function?

Comment: can you give me a more detaild description of how i can do it? I dont understant what you did

Answer (score 0):

Save sukkers_g values into an array sukkers for future using.

**JS**

```
var person = '[{"navn":"Imsdal Aktiv", "volum":0.5, "sukker_g":27.3},    {"navn":"Coca-Cola", "volum":0.5, "sukker_g":53}, {"navn":"Iste", "volum":0.5, "sukker_g":44}, {"navn":"Red Bull", "volum":0.250, "sukker_g":27.5}, {"navn":"Iskaffe", "volum":0.330, "sukker_g":16.5},    {"navn":"Frappuchino", "volum":0.250, "sukker_g":25.5}, {"navn":"Solrik", "volum":0.250, "sukker_g":29.7}, {"navn":"Litago", "volum":0.5, "sukker_g":20}, {"navn":"Vitamin Boost", "volum":0.5, "sukker_g":20},    {"navn":"Solbærsirup", "volum":0.250, "sukker_g":24.5},    {"navn":"Sjokolademelk", "volum":0.250, "sukker_g":12.5}]';
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var objects_array = JSON.parse(person); 
var sukkers=[];   
for(var i = 0; i < objects_array.length; i++) {
    var opt = objects_array[i].navn;
    sukkers[i] =objects_array[i].sukker_g;
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);         
 }
alert(sukkers.join("\n"));
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='selectNumber'>selectNumber</div>
```

Working Example in **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/suexqLvg/)**